# how to identify whether a number is a binary code or a decimal in C

Tags: c

I've tried making a calculator that first reads the input from the user and then decides wheter the input is in binary or in decimal and then converts it.
i got almost everything but can't come up with the identifier! here's the code that i got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a;
char num[100];
int number[100];
int decimal_binary (int n);
int binary_decimal (int n);

void errorcode(void);
bool bin, decim;

int main (){
  bin (false);
  decim (false);
  printf ("enter a number: ");
  gets (num);
  a = strlen(num);
  if (a > 8){
    errorcode();
    //printf("That is an invalid number!");
    //exit(45);
  }

  for (int i=0; i < a; i++){
    number[i] = num[i] -'0';
    printf("%d", number[i]);
  }

  int decimal_binary(int n){
    int rem, i=1, binary = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        rem =n%2;
        n/=2;
        binary+=rem *i;
        i*=10;
    }
    return binary;
  }

  int binary_decimal(int n)
  {
    int decimal = 0, i=0, rem;
    while (n!-0){
        rem = n%10;
        n/=10;
        decimal += rem *pow(2,i);
        ++i;
    }
    return decimal;
  }
}

void errorcode(void){
  printf("That is an invalid number!");
  exit(45);
}
```

Comment: So would 1001 be binary or decimal?

Comment: Furthermore, if you read the input as integers, they will be in binary format, like everything else inside your program. This question doesn't make any sense, vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such way to detect whether the number entered was binary or decimal just by analysing the characters of the number entered.  However, if you study the Microsoft Windows calculator application that ships along with the OS, the "programmer" type of calculator takes an input whether the entered number is binary or decimal from the user, then internally in its code it would check whether the entered number was a valid binary or decimal number.

In short, your code will have to tell the user to specify what number is entered.

I would recommend studying the Microsoft calculator application's "programmer" type calc in order to help you understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct answer to this question is that binary numbers can be identified with the 0b prefix. Ex: 0b11111111 is the byte 0xFF, or 255 decimal. Notice the 0x prefix on the hex number. Decimal numbers have no prefix.. In fact, if you lead your 'decimal' number with a zero, the compiler will think that it is an octal number and treat it as base 8.